# How to use Collate in Hibernate for french char set

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, collate

Hi I'm trying to use collate on a view which has column name `per_va_first_name` when I use the following query :

```
SELECT *
 FROM person_view
 WHERE NLSSORT(per_va_first_name, 'NLS_SORT = FRENCH_AI') = NLSSORT('mickaël', 'NLS_SORT  =FRENCH_AI')
```

I get the error

> ORA-12702: invalid NLS parameter string used in SQL function

I'm new to oracle and this `nlssort`. Can anyone help me in pointing out what's my mistake? 
And at the same time I want to use collate in Hibernate for Java. Same french char set.

Edit:

When I use these commands in sql

```
alter session set nls_sort=French_AI;
alter session set nls_comp=linguistic;
```

I get the desired output when this query is executed

```
SELECT * FROM v_myuser_search_test_ea4 where per_va_first_name like 'Mickaël%'
```

How to do this in Hibernate? Is there a way I can append 'CI' to French_AI to make it 'French_AI_CI'

Answer (score -1):

According to Oracle documentation found on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions113.htm#SQLRF51562

you might change your query to

```
SELECT *
FROM person_view
ORDER BY NLSORT(per_va_first_name, 'NLS_SORT = FRENCH_AI_CI')
```

Hibernate should understand it, however you are already losing database portability as this is Oracle-specific function.

Comment: I tried it, in vain. It just returns me one record with name as 'mickaël' not all the records with 'mickael'. Bdw I was making mistake with French_CI_AI. I dunno what's the problem but either supports French_AI or French_CI but not both.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand your initial question. Can you alter properties on database level for NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP?

Comment: As far as I remember, Oracle JDBC driver does not have an option to set these parameters, it uses underlying VM character set and encoding for collators. I had similar problem with WebSphere application server on Linux talking to Oracle database that was on UTF-8. Collators did not work until I set VM properties user.language and user.country (for your case it would be -Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=FR).